Tableau Viz tooltip to filter with dashboard
I have a dashboard in tableau and on one of the KPI cards there is a viz tooltip of some data in a table. When I click something in the dashboard it filters everything down to that but the tooltip viz doesn’t filter. How do I apply that?
